# How do I add a value to a list with button click?

Tags: javascript, appendchild

I'm having trouble using the appendChild function...

here's my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form oninput="x.value=((parseFloat(winning_number.value)%(parseFloat(total_key_value.value)*100*2))/(parseFloat(total_key_value.value)*2)).toFixed(2)">
<input type="number" id="winning_number" value="" placeholder="Winning Number"> ~ 
<input type="number" id="total_key_value" value="" placeholder = "Total (Keys)">
= <output name="x" for="winning_number total_key_value"></output>%
</form>

<button type="submit" onclick="document.getElementById("container").appendChild(li);">Submit</button>


<ol id="list"></ol>

</body>
</html>
```

i enter 2 numbers and it will calculates the result using a formula.

how can i make a button that will add the x value to a list once clicked?

also, i want to be able to delete items from the list if that's possible

im very new to javascript as you might realize

thanks

Comment: `<button type="submit" onclick="document.getElementById("container").appendChild(li);">Submit</button>`

on your example your ol id is not **container**

Comment: You have a quoting problem. The quotes before `container` is matching the quote after `onclick=`, so it's ending the attribute. Use single quotes around strings when they're inside a double-quoted attribute, or vice versa.

Comment: Where do you set the variable `li`?

Comment: Thanks guys, im going to do these both.

Comment: You should put what you want to do into a function. Adding a row to a table is not a simple one-liner that can easily fit into the `onclick` attribute. You need to call `document.createElement` to create the new `li`, fill the element with the appropriate contents, then call `appendChild`. You might want to learn jQuery, it makes it a little easier.

Comment: wow this is a lot harder than i thought

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code  https://jsfiddle.net/bfmpkc7p/2/

```
<form oninput="x.value=((parseFloat(winning_number.value)%(parseFloat(total_key_value.value)*100*2))/(parseFloat(total_key_value.value)*2)).toFixed(2)">
<input type="number" id="winning_number" value="" placeholder="Winning Number"> ~ 
<input type="number" id="total_key_value" value="" placeholder = "Total (Keys)">
= <output id="outputvalue" name="x" for="winning_number total_key_value"></output>%
</form>
<button id="boton" type="submit">Submit</button>
<ol id="list"></ol>
```

And javascript

```
$('#boton').click( function() {
  value = $("#outputvalue").html();
    $('#list').append('<li>'+value+'</li>'); 
});

$(document).on('click', 'li', function () { $(this).remove(); });
```

When you click on button, the function create a li tag with a value in output tag with id=outputvalue in the ol with id = list

Update!! click on li element and delete.
https://jsfiddle.net/bfmpkc7p/3/

Comment: you can add css style to list.

Comment: @HappyG Thanks! if it was helpful give it your vote and select it as an answer to close the thread!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here but from a quick glimpse, I found a typo in your onclick.

```
onclick="document.getElementById("container").appendChild(li);"
```

You're having problems with your apostrophes. If you're using a "", then the inner ones need to be either \" \" or simply put ' '

This would work:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('container').appendChild(li);"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to Javascript, then you should learn jQuery. We can do this more clean and handy with jQuery.

```js
$("input").change(function(e) {
  var winning_number = $("#winning_number").val();
  var total_key_value = $("#total_key_value").val();
  var res = ((parseFloat(winning_number) % (parseFloat(total_key_value) * 100 * 2)) / (parseFloat(total_key_value) * 2)).toFixed(2);
  $("#result").val(res);
});

$("#submit").click(function(e) {
  var val = $("#result").val();
  $("#list").append("<li>" + val + "</li>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

</div>
<form id="calculation">
  <input type="number" id="winning_number" value="" placeholder="Winning Number"> ~
  <input type="number" id="total_key_value" value="" placeholder="Total (Keys)"> =
  <input id="result"> %
</form>
<span id="text"></span>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>


<ol id="list"></ol>
```